# Volume backup/restore on docker not working as expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose file to run an instance of the image which I pull from an online source.

I backed up this image using:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from container1 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvfz /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/myapp
```

, did some changes to it, then attempted to restore it using the following command:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from container2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /var/lib/myapp && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

However, the restoration (extraction) of the zipped backup is taking place inside the `cd /var/lib/myapp`  on my host server not inside the container. Is there a way to indicate that the path is of a container not a host

Comment: In the last command what is the value of $(pwd) ?

Comment: @TolisGerodimos the directory which contains the backup .tar file. The same as the first command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by modifying the commands to the following:

Backup:

```
 docker run --rm --volumes-from container1 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar -cvzf /backup/backup.tar -C /var/lib/mapp ./
```

Restore:

```
 docker run --rm --volumes-from container2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /var/lib/myapp && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

Then ran:

```
docker-compose restart
```